# Objects created in constructor become null

Tags: c#, object, null

I am a novice programmer and i need some help understanding what is wrong. 
I create an object in which constructor's I create my players. However as soon as I finish my constructor all objects craeted inside the other are null. Is it not possible for an object to create objects? if not how can I design my program so I can access my player objects from any class.?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tablero tablero = new Tablero();
        tablero.test();    //now Tablero doesnt have player
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Tablero
    {
        Buscador busc1;
        public Tablero()
        {
            Buscador busc1 = new Buscador(50);
            //test();       same problem
        }
        public void test()
        {
            Console.Write(busc1.getPosX());
        }
    }

    public class Buscador
    {
        int posx;
        public Buscador(int posx)
        {
            this.posx = posx;
        }
        public int getPosX()
        {
            return posx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint:  Look at compiler _warnings_...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have defined `Buscador busc1;` in the main body of the class so instead of:

```
Buscador busc1 = new Buscador(50);
```

simply write

```
busc1 = new Buscador(50);
```

By doing the first one, you are saying that you want to create an instance of Buscador local to the method instantiating it. Therefore, it is removed once the method ends and is not accessible from any other methods.

`Buscador busc1;` defined outside of the `Tablero()` constructor is accessible to any methods in the entire class.

See this MSDN article about scoping:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Buscador busc1 = new Buscador(50);` becomes now a local variable in constructor, and you're calling `busc1` instance variable through the test method. As to solve this problem don't make other reference variable in constructor. Use instance reference variable like: `busc1 = new Buscador(50);`